# Can I use flutter assets for local notification attachments on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-local-notification

I am using the flutter_local_notifications package to show notifications in my flutter app. I would like to show an image with my notifications on iOS by adding the image to the "attachments" array in IOSNotificationDetails.

```
final iosNotificationDetails = IOSNotificationDetails(
    attachments: [IOSNotificationAttachment('assets/image.png')],
);
```

I have seen the example to download the image from a URL and save it in the application documents directory, but would like to know if there is a way to either load an image directly from the flutter assets or from a file in my iOS project.

Answer (score 1):

For a local image you can do like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

Future<String> getImageFromAssets(String asset) async {
    final byteData = await rootBundle.load(asset);

    final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/${asset.split('/').last}');
    await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

    return file.path;
  }
```

And then save this String in a variable

```
final image = await getImageFromAssets('assets/image.png');
```

Finally, assign this value to iosNotificationDetails.

```
attachments: [IOSNotificationAttachment(image)],
```

Answer (score 0):

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');

final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

return file;
}